# Anyone has any recommendations for a good Wcf Proxy Generator?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I've been using "Exception Handling WCF Proxy Generator" available at http://wcfproxygenerator.codeplex.com this is a good solid product but it hasn't been updated in a while.  It is pre-.NET 4 and the current implementation only works on VS 2008.  I'm wondering if there is anything new out there?  Better yet, do I even need such a tool?  Has there been any changes in .NET 4 that would make such a tool obsolete?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to generate your proxies unless you really want to. You can [build a reusable service client](http://brandonzeider.me/2011/microsoft-net/building-a-reusable-service-client/) using a [ChannelFactory](http://brandonzeider.me/2011/net-faq/using-channelfactory/) with very little effort. Using the code in the link as an example, you would just add whatever cleanup/logging/exception handling code needed, and you have a reusable client without having to generate code.

Comment: I would like to create the client in one place then pass it around throughout my application as a service contract, can I do this?  I have to hack WcfProxyGenerator to allow me to do this.  Also, it's not clear what the Wcf Interceptor really does.

Comment: The interceptor intercepts calls to the proxy object created by the proxy generator (Castle), creates a channel from the specified service using a channel factory, and invokes the specified operation on this channel.

I don't think creating the client in one place and passing it around is a good idea. A better approach (if you want to consolidate this proxy creation) would be to use a static class.

Comment: You've been very helpful. This is what I am trying to do from a previous question a while back (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975242/how-do-i-pass-a-service-to-another-plugin).  Why is this a bad idea and are there any examples of such a static class.

Comment: No problem. It's just a "generally" bad idea in my opinion, you can certainly do it. Perhaps "bad idea" is a little too strong, I just don't think it buys you anything if you have a reusable service client.